# Spring Data + Hibernate: Trouble with insert with two tables (Pattern and Child). Invalid column name

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, spring-data

I'm very happy to participate in this site. I'm novice in Stack Overflow, but there's always a first time :).

At the moment I'm working with Spring Data 1.3.0 and Hibernate 4.1.9, using JPA 2.0 over Java for generate querys based on repositories and the Database is SQL Server 2008. I need to make an insert operation with two tables: A pattern table called PATTERN_TABLE. This table is referenced for another called CHILD_TABLE and their relationship is one-to-many. My guide for develop a solution for this requirement is the follow link: [Hibernate one-to-many mapping using annotations](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/17/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-using-annotations/), and I'm trying to adapt this for spring data support (repository management). However it's fails because Hibernate, for the insert, try to find a column that doesn't exists in the CHILD_TABLE table (in database) and nor in the mapping entity. I don't know why Hibernate tries to find this column name and I suppouse that it's an alias (called patternTable_CODIGO). The error is defined by the following log registry:

```
Hibernate: insert into GDA.dbo.PATTERN_TABLE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
(...)
Hibernate: insert into GDA.dbo.CHILD_TABLE (COLUMN_CHILD_A, COLUMN_CHILD_B, patternTable_CODIGO) values (?, ?, ?) --->patternTable_CODIGO doesn't exists in the database!!!
2013-09-19 18:05:12,967 [Thread-18] [SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions] WARN  SQL Error: 207, SQLState: 42S22
2013-09-19 18:05:12,967 [Thread-18] [SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions] ERROR [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'patternTable_CODIGO'.
2013-09-19 18:05:12,967 [Thread-18] [SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions] WARN  SQL Error: 8180, SQLState: HY000
2013-09-19 18:05:12,968 [Thread-18] [SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions] ERROR [FMWGEN]        [SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'patternTable_CODIGO'.; 
SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'patternTable_CODIGO'.
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
   (...)
   at sun.proxy.$Proxy274.save(Unknown Source)
   at co.com.myproject.impl.PatternTableServiceImpl.guardar(PatternTableServiceImpl.java:25)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   (...)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
   at sun.proxy.$Proxy275.guardar(Unknown Source)
   at co.com.myproject.principal.GenerarPlano.inicio(GenerarPlano.java:102)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'patternTable_CODIGO'.
   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
   at sun.proxy.$Proxy264.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
   at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
   at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2936)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447)
   at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3MergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3MergeEventListener.java:71)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:236)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:216)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:913)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:895)
   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:288)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:383)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:412)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:353)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:329)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
   at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:220)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:903)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:891)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor280.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
   at sun.proxy.$Proxy256.merge(Unknown Source)
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:353)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333)
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
   ... 33 more
```

This is the `PatternTable` entity:

```
package co.com.myproject.persistencia;
// ... libraries
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PATTERN_TABLE", schema = "dbo", catalog = "GDA")
public class PatternTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int codigo;

    // ... a lot of mapped fields...

    private Set<ChildTable> childTable = new HashSet<ChildTable>(0);

    public PatternTable() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CODIGO")
    public int getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    // ... a lot of getters and setters...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="CODIGO_PATTERN_TABLE")
    public Set<ChildTable> getChildTable() {
            return childTable;
    }

    public void setChildTable(Set<ChildTable> childTable) {
            this.childTable = childTable;
    }
}
```

This is the `ChildTable` entity

```
package co.com.myproject.persistencia;
//... libs
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_TABLE", schema = "dbo", catalog = "GDA")
public class ChildTable implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int codigo;
    private PatternTable patternTable;
    //... more attribures

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CODIGO", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getCodigo() {
            return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@ManyToOne
public PatternTable getPatternTable() {
    return patternTable;
}

public void setPatternTable(PatternTable patternTable) {
    this.patternTable = patternTable;
}

// ... more getters and setters
}
```

This is my repository interface for `PatternTable`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface PatternTableRepository extends JpaRepository<PatternTable, Integer> {
    List<PatternTable> findByPatternParameter(String patternParameter);
    // ... more code next
}
```

My service method is defined for:

```
public void guardar(PatternTable patternTable) {
    patternTableRepository.save(patternTable);
}
```

And the `patternTable`'s object collects one or more `childTable` by follows:

```
childTable = new ChildTable();
//...set attributes of childTable...
patternTable.getChildTable().add(childTable);
```

I'm sorry if my english is not fluent. I'll try to found a solution, but if you can help me I'll appreciate this aid. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I can't to development my ideal solution for this trouble, but I can to develop a very quickly and easy solution. This works as follows:

1. Write some changes in `PatternTable` and `ChildTable` entity beans. In `ChildTable`, after the @ManyToOne annotation, add a FetchType and the JoinColumn as follows:

   ```
   //Entity definition and getters / setters...        
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGO_PATTERN_TABLE", nullable = false)
   public PatternTable getPatternTable() {
       return patternTable;
   }
   //More getters and setters...
   ```

   Moreover, in `PatternTable` entity bean, modify the @OneToMany relationship as follows:

   ```
   //Entity definition and getters / setters... 
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patternTable")
   public Set<ChildTable> getChildTable() {
       return childTable;
   }
   //More getters and setters...
   ```
2. Modify the save method for the entity beans. First time, I saved the `PatternTable` entity bean without the Set of `ChildTable`s. After that, I associated the `ChildTable`s' set with their respective `PatternTable` and I created a new repository by `ChildTable` to save these.

Thanks a lot for review this question and sorry for my poor english! :)